# Property 'slug' does not exist on type 'ParsedUrlQuery | undefined'

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I am trying to get the *path* of my page on `getServerSideProps`, but the type of `params` is ***object***

What I need to do to get as string?

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const { slug } = context.params // Property 'slug' does not exist on type 'ParsedUrlQuery | undefined'.ts(2339)

  return {
    props: {
    },
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that you look for code that look like this

```js
import { ParsedUrlQuery } from "querystring";

interface Params extends ParsedUrlQuery {
  slug: string;
}

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const { slug } = context.params as Params;

  return {
    props: {
    },
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the path as a String, you can try `context.req.url`. (See the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering) for the full list of `context` properties).

For the dynamic parameter, it depends on what you've named the page, for example if you have a Blog post page, with a `pages/posts/[post].js` file, the slug will be in `context.params.post` as opposed to `context.params.slug`.

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: Its slug the paramenter ([slug].tsx), but how to type it? I got the error: Property 'slug' does not exist on type 'ParsedUrlQuery | undefined'

Comment: Is `const slug = context.params?.slug as string` correct?

Comment: Ohhh interesting! I wonder why it seems to be interpreting `context.params` as type `ParsedUrlQuery ` 

Comment: And `const slug = context.params?.slug as string` looks pretty darn correct to me!

Comment: I'm not positive that this is the same issue, but perhaps try rendering it like the answer to this issue [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/16522#discussioncomment-55590)

Comment: And [here's](https://wallis.dev/blog/nextjs-getstaticprops-and-getstaticpaths-with-typescript) another post with some information about what might be the issue, and a proposed solution.